# Kotlin filter String by List of indices

Tags: kotlin, filter, collections

How do I filter a List of indices out of a String? Thanks.

```
val s = "abcdef"
val indices = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val filtered = s.filterIndexed {i, _ -> i != /* ??? */ }
// outcome: filtered = "af"
```

Comment: `i !in indices`

Comment: Tenfour04 That did it, thanks!